# Using functions in postgres query skips the index. Any solution to use functions with index applied

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

For eg:

If lower function is removed, the query performance is better than using lower. Using lower skips the index. Is

```
SELECT X.article_number, X.online_description
FROM articles X
WHERE LOWER(X.online_description) % usp_get_search_terms ('coke');
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

An index can only be used to speed up a `WHERE` condition if the condition is of the following form:

```
<indexed expression> <operator> <constant>
```

Here `<operator>` must be an operator in the *operator class* of the index, and `<constant>` need not really be a constant, but fixed for the duration of the index scan.

I assume that `%` is the similarity operator from the `pg_trgm` extension. Then you need either a GIN index with the `gin_trgm_ops` operator class or a GiST index with the `gist_trgm_ops` operator class.

Since trigram operations are case insensitive anyway, you should remover the `lower()` from the query. Otherwise, you'd have to create the index on `lower(online_description)`, which would be a waste of CPU.

Comment: lower(online_description) = <constant> , any alternative to use this without indexing the lower(online_description)

Comment: No way. It cannot be done. Fix your query or fix the index.